# External YAML property file and normal properties file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, properties

This is how I have set up external configuration file:

```
/** for .yaml file
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:waterlvl.yaml")
@ConfigurationProperties("Alerts")
public class WaterLvlAlertConfig {

/** for .properties file
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:waterlvl.properties")
public class WaterLvlConfig {
```

Properties are not being picked up, and my files are inside the resources file. I think the path I'm providing is wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you mean both the files `waterlvl.yaml` and `waterlvl.properties` are not picked?

Comment: yes , both are not being picked. property files are inside resources folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spring boot @PropertySource cannot be used when using .yaml configuration. Refer to point 24.6.4 YAML shortcomings in externalized configuration documents. Also, a similar question is answered earlier, refer - [Spring boot external configuration of property file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020491/spring-boot-external-configuration-of-property-file)